# How to iterate this sin equation?

Tags: c

I can't create the correct file. the equation in the program doesn't iterate through and it only writes the same sum at as many samples as were requested.

for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LEN 256

int main ()
{
   FILE * fp;
   double i=0; //sample count
   double y=0; //y values
   double f=0; //frequency
   double t=0; //time

   /* open the file for writing*/
   fp = fopen ("1.dat","w");
//fprintf(fp, "sample #\ty-value\n"); 

printf("Enter the frequency in hertz: ");
scanf("%lg", &f);
printf("Enter the number of samples : ");
scanf("%lg", &t);



   /* write 1 seconds of time data into the file stream*/
   for(i = 0; i < t;i++){

//y=sin(i*M_PI/180);
y=sin(2*M_PI*f*t);

//       fprintf (fp, "%g  %g\n",i ,y);
       fprintf (fp, "%g\n",y);
   }

   /* close the file*/  
   fclose (fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first item in a for-loop-statement is only called one time. So y=sin(2*M_PI*f*t) doesn't change over the iterations. If you want to update y you have to do it inside the for-loop.

Comment: And please correct your indentation.

Comment: I tried it like this before and same result. failure!   /* write 1 seconds of time data into the file stream*/
   for(i = 0; i < t;i++){

//y=sin(i*M_PI/180);
y=sin(2*M_PI*f*t);

//       fprintf (fp, "%g  %g\n",i ,y);
       fprintf (fp, "%g\n",y);
   }
 
   /* close the file*/  
   fclose (fp);
   return 0;
}

Comment: Should I be able to do it with one for loop or two? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question with the further code. It's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: It is not easy to help you cause your code is wrong and doesn't compile. So please change it to a complete example of your problem which compiles and gives the error you describe. Problems: The initial value of t is missing, f is missing and I don't think you really want to have that dependency between t and i.

Comment: "Should I be able to do it with one for loop or two?" Most probably yes but I'm not sure if I 100% understand what you want to do...

Comment: I posted the full program with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you really want to do:

Your control variable is neither i nor t but i/t which is i-th sample of t samples in a second:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LEN 256

int main ()
{
    FILE * fp;
    unsigned int i=0; //sample count
    double y=0; //y values
    double f=0; //frequency
    unsigned int t=0; //time

    /* open the file for writing*/
    fp = fopen ("1.dat","w");

    printf("Enter the frequency in hertz: ");
    scanf("%lg", &f);
    printf("Enter the number of samples : ");
    scanf("%u", &t);
    /* write 1 seconds of time data into the file stream*/
    for(i = 0; i < t;i++){
        y=sin(2*M_PI*f*i/t);
        fprintf (fp, "%g\n",y);
    }

    /* close the file*/  
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use doubles as a loop index. You might end up with an iteration too few, or an iteration extra, due to truncation/roundoff errors (in the case shown, it will probably work since the doubles are actually integer values, but yo9u should never rely on that)

Comment: @FredK It is the code of he OP. But you are right. t should be an unsigned int and i should also. I change that. Even if I think it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Richard FredK is right and you should care about that limitation.

Comment: user6556709 I do care, honest.